Why does stim::FrameSimulator work?
I have read the main stim paper and understood it.
I understand the concept of propogating a Pauli Frame and having a reference Frame. I understand that we want to multiply Z into a pauli frame with 50% probability after a reset or a measurement. What's tripping me up is that: why would it work? Why would it give expected results?
I can't seem to find a proof anywhere. Maybe there is some logic that I am missing.
One intermediate result that would be nice to understand is that in a given circuit: why is each measurement either random or deterministic independent of the results of the previous measurements? I assume that this is a correct statement, since stim has a function count_determined_measurements.
Another thing that I can't understand is: why does the stim::frame_simulator not have the X, Y and Z gates? They are just skipped here. Are we not supposed to apply Clifford gates by the same rules going from Pauli Frame $F$ to a $C^{-1}FC$? For some reason I can't make up an example where skipping those gates would break the algorithm. Which makes me think that there should be some mathematics that I am missing.
Any links, thoughts and questions are much appreciated!


What's tripping me up is that: why would it work? Why would it give expected results?

It's splitting the simulation into two pieces: the noiseless part and the noisy part. You can think of it as noisy gates being intercepted by the frame simulator, and other gates being allowed to pass through to the tableau simulator (acting on the frame when passing through the frame simulator). This is obviously correct, it's maybe just a bit weird to track Paulis in a second place (the frame simulator) when the tableau simulator could already have handled them.
The tricky part is to convince yourself that you don't need to redo the noiseless simulation each time. The noiseless samples are interchangeable and reusable. You can just do the noiseless sim once, and reuse those outcomes every time. The key thing to prove, I think, is that if you have a noiseless sample A and a noiseless sample B then you can transform A into B merely by varying the random Z errors injected at resets. Those random Z errors at resets are enforcing that the samples are interchangeable.

Another thing that I can't understand is: why does the stim::frame_simulator not have the X, Y and Z gates? They are just skipped> Keep in mind the frame simulator (or stim.FlipSimulator in the
python API) is just tracking Pauli errors.

They do nothing because when $P$ is a Pauli product and $E$ is a Pauli product, $P^{-1} E P = \pm E$. The sign of errors isn't important, so this just leaves $E$ unchanged thus requiring no changes to the simulator state.
You can see lots of other examples in there of Paulis being ignored, e.g. S and S_DAG being handled by the same code because they differ by a Pauli.
